# Why is my copy constructor being called when I return *this from a class member function?

Tags: c++

I know my copy constructors and overloaded operators are rather arbitrary in this case, but I looking for someone to verify if i'm making them correctly, as well as using *this correctly.

Also, could someone tell me why the copy constructor is called every time I return *this or an object of type Rectangle from any of my overloaded operators?

```
class Rectangle
{
    private:
        int length;
        int width;
        static int counter;
    public:
        Rectangle(int len = 0, int w = 0)
        {
            length = len;
            width = w;
            counter++;
        }
        ~Rectangle()
            { counter--; }
        static int getCounter()
            { return counter; }

        Rectangle(const Rectangle &);
        Rectangle operator+ (const Rectangle &);
        Rectangle operator= (const Rectangle &);
};

int Rectangle::counter = 0;

Rectangle::Rectangle(const Rectangle &right) : Rectangle()
{
    width = right.width;
    length = right.length;
}

Rectangle Rectangle::operator+ (const Rectangle &right)
{
    width += right.width;
    length += right.length;
    return *this;
}

Rectangle Rectangle::operator= (const Rectangle &right)
{
    width = right.width;
    length = right.length;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: `: Rectangle()` is wrong in the constructor definition.

Comment: Is there anyway I could properly increment the counter? If I use the copy constructor to make one object equal the other, it won't invoke the default constructor, and therefore won't increment counter.

Comment: Increment the counter in every constructor definition.

Comment: What's the difference between what I did and your solution? Wouldn't both of them increment counter?

Comment: Your solution won't compile, that's the difference.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's a delegating constructor...?

Comment: Although you might as well delegate to `Rectangle(right.length, right.width)` instead and skip the assignment in the body. And while we are at this, that constructor needs to be `explicit`, and possibly split.

Comment: operator+ should be const, returning a new object which is *left + right*. *this should be unmodified through operator +. Imagine you had `int b = 1, c = 2; int a = b + c;` you wouldn't expect `b` to be changed by this...

Comment: Man you guys don't consider your audience at all, do you?

Comment: @Matimio See [operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Comment: @T.C. Is this new since c++11 standard?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: yes it is since C++11.

Answer (score 5):

Others have commented on how returning by value is invoking your copy constructor so I'm just going to answer the first part of the question:

> if i'm making them correctly, as well as using *this correctly.

Your operator overloads are wrong:

```
Rectangle Rectangle::operator+ (const Rectangle &right)
{
    width += right.width;
    length += right.length;
    return *this;
}
```

this modifies `*this` and then returns a copy of it. That's not what you'd expect:

```
int b = 1, c = 2;
int a = b + c;
```

In the above, b and c are unmodified. A new value is produced and stored in a.

```
Rectangle Rectangle::operator+ (const Rectangle &right) const
{
    Rectangle newValue(*this);  // copy ctor temporary
    newValue.length += right.length;
    newValue.width += right.width;
    return newValue;
}
```

or if you've overloaded `operator+=` you could write it in terms of that:

```
Rectangle Rectangle::operator+ (const Rectangle &right) const
{
    Rectangle newValue(*this);  // copy ctor temporary
    newValue += right;
    return newValue;
}
```

The compiler will generally be able to perform [Return Value Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) and elide one of the copies that this code would otherwise produce.

Secondly:

```
Rectangle Rectangle::operator= (const Rectangle &right)
{
    width = right.width;
    length = right.length;
    return *this;
}
```

as you've learned, return-by-value returns a copy. operator= is supposed to return a reference to the current object:

```
Rectangle& Rectangle::operator= (const Rectangle& right)
{
    width = right.width;
    length = right.length;
    return *this;
}
```

Consider

```
a = b = c;
```

This executes

```
a.operator=(b.operator=(c));
```

returning a reference will save us a copy producing the parameter to a.operator=.

I'll finish with this suggestion for use of *this:

When you are returning a reference, *this says "return a reference to this concrete instance of my type". When you are returning a value and you say "*this" you say "return an rvalue (modifiable) instance of this class that *looks like this*", which invokes a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Copy constructor is getting called as you are returning the object by value which needs to be copied at caller side.

```
Rectangle Rectangle::operator= (const Rectangle &right)
{
    width = right.width;
    length = right.length;
    return *this;     <<<<<<<< copy constructor call.
}
```

You can avoid this copy if you return that object by reference.

```
Rectangle& Rectangle::operator= (const Rectangle &right)
{
    width = right.width;
    length = right.length;
    return *this;     <<<<<<<<<<<< No copy constructor call.
}
```

Comment: How is this different than my answer?

Comment: @xaxxon It goes straight to the point and doesn't show a bad signature for `operator+`? (I didn't down-vote yours BTW.)

Answer (score -1):

> Also, could someone tell me why the copy constructor is called every
>   time I return *this or an object of type Rectangle from any of my
>   overloaded operators?

Your operators return `Rectangle` objects which have to be constructed based on the value of the `Rectangle` stored in `*this`.   Creating a `Rectangle` from a `Rectangle` is what a copy constructor does.

If you want to return the `this` `Rectangle` itself (instead of a copy), you'll want to return a reference to a Rectangle -- so `Rectangle&`

```
Rectangle & Rectangle::operator+ (const Rectangle &right)
```

Comment: It's a "solution" if you don't want the copy constructor to be called.  Though the implementation you have in operator+ is better suited for operator+=, since it modifies the operand.

Comment: `operator+` shouldn't return a reference... it was correct as posted in the question, returning by value.  (`+=` would return a reference to `*this`)

Comment: @TonyD He asked why the copy constructor was being called.   His code is terribly wrong in many fashions, but this is the reason his copy constructor is being called -- which was his specific question.  I specifically said *IF* he wants to return *this, then he should return a ref.  I didn't suggest his "business logic" was correct -- and in the question he specifies that the code is arbitrary.

Comment: @TonyD "I know my copy constructors and overloaded operators are rather arbitrary in this case"

Comment: Is it perfectly fine for classes to always call the copy constructor when returning objects from overloading operator functions? I feel like that would present some problem at some point.

Comment: @Matimio it's not incorrect, but it's often not the behavior you want, and it comes with the performance cost of creating a new object.   There are more advanced techniques which mitigate some of that cost (move constructor/move assignment), but that's not really relevant here.

Comment: Disregarding performance, would my class work properly? I'm just unsure if my most basic knowledge is incorrect.

Comment: In your code, when you say Rectangle foo = a + b;  `a` is getting changed, foo now has the same value as `a`, but if you change `a`, `foo` doesn't change.  If you change `foo`, then `a` doesn't change.   If you return a reference, changing one will change the other.   It simply depends what behavior you want.  For +, usually you don't change either `a` or `b` and return a new (copy constructed) element.   for +=, you would change `a` and return a reference to it. (`a` becomes `this` inside your operator+)

Comment: So how would I properly implement Rectangle foo = a + b, where a and b stay the same, while only changing foo?

Comment: @TonyD 's answer gives you some suggestions to that follow up question.

Answer (score -2):

> overloaded operators are rather arbitrary in this case, but I looking for someone to verify if i'm making them correctly, as well as using *this correctly.

Nope - not quite correct.

`Rectangle Rectangle::operator= (const Rectangle &right)` is usually written to return a `Rectangle&`, so other operations can be made on the assigned-to object, it can be passed as a function argument etc..

`Rectangle Rectangle::operator+(const Rectangle &right)` is implemented incorrectly.  It's common to first implement `+=` and then use that in the implementation of `+`, but if you want to write it independently it could be:

```
Rectangle Rectangle::operator+(Rectangle right) const
{
    right.width += width;
    right.length += length;
    return right;
}
```

That way, the `right` is parameter is by-value, so changes to it don't affect the caller, and you can modify it and return it by value.  This might seem inefficient, but the by-value return is typically optimised away (it's called a Return Value Optimisation - RVO).

The other approach I mentioned looks like this...

```
Rectangle& operator+=(const Rectangle& rhs)
{
     length += rhs.length;
     width += rhs.width;
     return *this;
}

Rectangle operator+(Rectangle rhs) const
{
     return (rhs += *this);
}
```

That said, if there are any implicit constructors for your type, it's necessary to make `+` a non-member operator, so the left-hand-side argument gets a change to be implicitly constructed:

```
Rectangle operator+(const Rectangle& lhs, const Rectangle& rhs)
{
    return Rectangle(lhs.length + rhs.length, lhs.width + rhs.width);
}
```

> Also, could someone tell me why the copy constructor is called every time I return `*this` or an object of type Rectangle from any of my overloaded operators?

In the code in your question, the return type is `Rectangle` (not by reference), and you return `*this`: what that does is make a copy of the object on which the function's invoked and returns that copy.  The copy constructor is used to create the copy.

Comment: You didn't answer his question.

Comment: It's worth maybe a mention for RVO.

Comment: @xaxxon: I had addressed the first question (well, more literally a request *"looking for someone to verify"*) in the body of Matimio's post before your comment, and have had time since to address the second question (also asked in the title).  Cheers.